# iOS Core Data Saving MOC issue due to Validation rules context

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record with the Core Data framework, and I've run into issues saving deleted objects from my MOC.  I have a Patient NSManagedObject that has a set of Notes NSManagedObjects, so MOs look like like so:

Patient.h

```
@interface Patient : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *notes;    
@end

@interface Patient (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addNotes:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeNotes:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

Notes.h

```
@interface Note : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * creationDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * noteText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Patient *patient;
@end
```

I also have validation rules to make sure the noteText property is not null or empty.  Now in my view controller in the viewDidLoad method I'm creating a new note managed object using:

```
Note* lNote = [Note MR_createInContext:localContext];
```

So, the note is created instantly once the view loads, ready for the noteText property to be modified via a UITextView.  If the user does not enter any text and presses Save the validation triggers and prevents the save, which is all good.

The problem occurs when I click on my notes archive folder button which is in this same view controller, once pressed, it presents a modal view controller and lets the user either load or delete notes, since I'm trying to delete a note from this archive screen, I have to rollback the previous note I created in the viewDidLoad method, so that I can delete the notes and save the default context, otherwise when I'm trying to save the deleted objects the validation rule for noteText property kicks in from the MOC.

I notice that this is more of a logical or work flow type of problem, but I want to prevent the rollback of the note created in the defaultContext and still be able to save the defaultContext with the deleted notes.

I've tried using different MOC but that presented more issues, one MOC for retrieving the patients and another one for creating notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a different managed object context is the correct solution for your problem. A MOC is a "scratchpad" and you need two scratchpads in the scenario you describe. You are essentially interrupting the note creation process with another note editing process.

That being said, you could just delete the empty note and recreate it when the other controller is dismissed. You could also set the note text to `@""`. There are all kinds of hacky ways to accomplish this, but using two MOCs is the cleanest method.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've tried using two different MOCs, but then I run into issues of something along the lines of "MOC belong to a different object", and when I create a new note with a new context then try to save it to the patient's notes list I get the same error about context mismatch.  I've tried googling on how to properly merge contexts, do you happen to have any links on the matter?  Thank you again.

Comment: It's quite simple, really, because in your case you are not really doing anything concurrently. Use a child context of your main context to deal with the editing, then when you are done you `save`, which pushes the changes to the main context, but are not persisted before you save again. There is no merging you need to do... Consider on of the other solutions I mention if this seems like too much.

Comment: Yea I cannot depend on a 2nd save for the deleted notes to be persisted because that is not always the case, incase they press the back button and don't want to save anything.  I'm currently using a hacky solution, and wanted to use a cleaner approach so I guess I might just have to stick with it.  Thank you again.

Comment: I am glad it can help you. If this is the case you should accept the answer.